# Add ES6 to ES5 transpilers in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I was able to deploy my Laravel Vue project online on Chrome and Firefox browsers it work great instead of Edge and IE that threw error saying **SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number**. I Googled that someone said it may be fixed by having ES6 to ES5 transpiler plugin or something similar enabled in Laravel Mix. Anyone, have you tried this before? I need a help. Thanks in advance.